# How to query Appengine Logs API for logs from ALL versions of app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I'm trying to use the [Logs API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/) to query for logs in my application. However, I'd like to query for logs for ALL versions of my application. The log service has a query parameter called majorVersionIds which you can set to a list of versions you want to query for or null for the current running version.

I'd like to query for ALL versions but I don't have a static list of all the versions to provide as the parameter. Any idea if there is a programatic way to get all the versions of an app?

My current solution would be to add a filter to all my versions which add the current version to  a list of all versions and use that but that seems hackey.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480101/request-logs-for-all-versions-of-google-app-engine-application ?

Answer (score -1):

You can download all available logs from the command line using [appcfg.py](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_logs).

In order to use the Logs API, you'd need to maintain a list of available version ids and provide it to [logservice.fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions).